# Get base64 of banner image in flows

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-actions, custom-list-actions

Is there a way to convert a banner image to a base64 using flows / power automate? Any of the `get content` actions for SharePoint does not work for banner image.

Answer (score 0):

My test flow for your reference:
[image]

Test result:
[image]

You can take it out like this：

[image]

Expression:

```
base64(outputs('Get_file_content_using_path')?['body'])
```

Comment: Thanks but you are using a `file`. I am not creating a new file. I want to get the banner image of a news post.

Comment: That is just a trigger action, just to get the corresponding picture.

Comment: I'm using `get file properties` to return the banner image url and this is the url being returned: `"https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?guidSite=42da643b9fb544f0ba63dca47012bb15&guidWeb=31b8be1c434b4f3ea7f697d9cb6b8161&guidFile=0c55849d5de6488ab7cf9163ae00ed51&ext=jpg"` which doesn't look right.

Comment: Could you get the image when you request the url in browser?

Comment: I figured out that the URL of the banner does not point to the individual site URL (in your case */sites/dev*) but instead links to the site-collection itself (https://mysp.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15). This is a problem for the action "Get File content using path" as it expects a site URL and seems not able to handle the base URL of the site collection.

Any tips how to copy the image to a temp SharePoint, get file content and delete the file afterwards?